# URL indexing in Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing

I want to check that a specific url is indexed in google using asp.net.
Is google provide any api, webmethod anything regarding this.

Please provide your comments if anybody know about this:

Syed,

Answer (score 0):

You can search Google for

> site:www.websiteyouwanttosearch.com

and parse the results for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html) to accomplish that. Search for a website's address like `?q=www.stackoverflow.com` and if you get any results, it's indexed.

To access this API in .NET you can use Google's [APIs Client Library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/).

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391972/check-if-url-is-indexed-by-google-using-php), it's probably **not a good idea** to to it **without using an official API** provided by Google because that would be against their [ToS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS).