# Google Page index

Tags: c#, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL indexing in Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089640/url-indexing-in-google)

I would like to know if it's possible to check if URL is indexed by Google in C#
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Google Webmaster Tools API](http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html)