# I want to know the index of my website specific page on Google search engine

Tags: google-search

How can I find the index of specific web page of my website on google search engine? For instance I write the keywords in the textbox of google search engine as follows:

"Deploy ASP.NET MVC" and press enter. Google gives me result like **About 1,330,000 results (0.07 seconds)**, but I could not find the results on first 10 result pages. How should I find on which index page the following web page exists on google search results?

http://www.raishussain.com/asp-net-mvc/deploy-asp-net-mvc/

I tried to find the technique but I did not find any solution, kindly help me to know the way, because I can not click the 1000 result pages to see where my web page exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if URL is indexed by Google using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391972/check-if-url-is-indexed-by-google-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific tool which can help you in this case. 
As the algorithm for google keeps changing very frequently and its confidential

You can try following websites, But there is no guarantee to get the 100% accurate.

http://www.keywordenvy.com/

http://www.keywordrankchecker.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer is not valid anymore, because the links provided are outdated.

As @zanlok already [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391972/check-if-url-is-indexed-by-google-using-php): one should better refer to the Google API in order not to violate their ToS.

In regards to the question read here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357

> Don't use unauthorized computer programs to submit pages, check
>   rankings, etc. Such programs consume computing resources and violate
>   our Terms of Service. Google does not recommend the use of products
>   such as WebPosition Gold™ that send automatic or programmatic queries
>   to Google.